# How to make variable private with constant in php

Tags: php, oop

Is it possible to make variable private as well as constant in php ?

I want to make the variable private so this variable can not access outside the class and
also want to make the variable constant because I don't want to access constant variable with class name  outside the class

Please anybody suggest me the answer.
Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

First, your PHP **variable** can be always set to `private` `public` or `protected` with the respective keyword.

Second, your PHP class **constant** *cannot* be set ot another scope than public. So both these syntax are not valid: `public const A` `private const A`. You can only use `const A` inside your class.

If you want to make your *constant* privated, you should declare your **static member** as follows:

```
class A
{
   private static $a;
}
```

This class member can be call like a constant via `A::$a`, however, you can still modify its value.

Answer (score 0):

Use Private static properties in that case you will have the same variable throughout all objects and if you want to extend its scop to nested you can expose getter method to get its value and restrict variables settings.

Answer (score 0):

Constants can never be `private`.  They can only be `public`